# How can I stop JetBrains IDEs (PyCharm and WebStorm specifically) eating so much memory?

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a new M1 Max MBP with 64 GB of RAM, and yet I'm constantly plagued by the "Your system has run out of application memory" dialog.

This happens very regularly. If I restart PyCharm and WebStorm, I will be fine for a while, but eventually it gets like this anymore.

Is there a known memory leak? Both apps are up-to-date to the most recent release.

I understand that apps takes as much memory as possible to improve performance, but this should be up to the level that this dialog keeps showing up.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image: Your system has run out of application memory]

Comment: If you go to `Help | Change Memory Settings` what is your Maximum Heap Size set to?

Comment: @DavidBuck 2048 MiB for both IDEs.

Comment: What version are you using? If it's ignoring that setting and the only answer currently is from tech support saying to open a ticket, sounds like it could be a bug with your current version (although, weird that it's 2 tools...). You might consider changing versions

Answer (score 0):

Please collect memory snapshots in the IDE(s) when the issue occurs (**Help > Diagnostic tools > Capture memory snapshot**) and create a ticket in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/, attaching snapshots to it.

Some notes:

- do not set `Xmx` to big values in VMoptions unless your projects are huge and the IDEs run low of memory - it is expected that the JVM will consume all of the heap to make less GC cycles, especially during heavy computations, like on IDE start.
- the IDEs may spawn child processes (TypeScript language server, linters, etc.), the overall memory usage you can see in task manager is a sum of java process memory usage and javascript processes memory consumption; please observe which processes have the largest consumption when you launch the IDE
- note also that OS Task Manager is reporting the overall memory used by Java process which consists of Java application heap + JVM resources + whatever else, it's a native OS process vs. Java application running in JVM. Please see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018776919 for details